# How to display text attributes on map canvas PyQGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I have a layer of lines which has certain attributes:

[image]

There is the label attribute which will contain text, and the label location attribute which will be a point geometry.

How can I make the text show up near the point geometry?

Looks like I could maybe use an annotations layer but some examples I've seen look messy with a bunch of text boxes, I just want the text itself to display.

```
for feature in self.final_lines.getFeatures():
    label = feature['flight_line_label']
    location = feature['flight_line_label_location']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually an annotations layer is exactly what I needed, code:

```
def add_label_layer(self):
    QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers([layer.id() for layer in [self.notelayer] if layer !=None])
    self.notelayer = QgsAnnotationLayer('Annotations', QgsAnnotationLayer.LayerOptions(QgsProject.instance().transformContext()))
    for feature in self.final_lines.getFeatures():
        geom = feature['label_location'].split(';')[-1]
        label = feature['label']
        print(f'geom == {geom} , label === {label}')
        a = QgsAnnotationPointTextItem(label, QgsGeometry.fromWkt(geom).asPoint())
        a_id = self.notelayer.addItem(a)
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.notelayer)
```